# Building Inverted Index exceed the Java Heap Size

Tags: scala, hadoop, avro, scalding

This might be a very special case but after pounding on my head for a while I thought to get help from Stackoverflow community.

I am building an inverted index for large data set (One day worth of data from large system). The building of inverted index get executed as a map reduce job on Hadoop. Inverted index is build with the help of scala. Structure of the inverted index as follows: `{key:"New", ProductID:[1,2,3,4,5,...]}` these get written in to avro files.

During this process I run into Java Heap Size issue. I think the reason is that terms like "New" as I showed above contain large number of productId(s). I have a, rough idea where the issue could take place in my Scala code:

```
  def toIndexedRecord(ids: List[Long], token: String): IndexRecord = {
    val javaList = ids.map(l => l: java.lang.Long).asJava //need to convert from scala long to java long
    new IndexRecord(token, javaList)
  }
```

And this is how I use this method (It get used in many locations but same code structure and login get use)

```
  val titles = textPipeDump.map(vf => (vf.itemId, normalizer.customNormalizer(vf.title + " " + vf.subTitle).trim))
    .flatMap {
    case (id, title) =>
      val ss = title.split("\\s+")
      ss.map(word => (word, List(id)))
  }
    .filter(f => f._2.nonEmpty)
    .group
    .sum
    .map {
    case (token, ids) =>
      toIndexedRecord(ids, token)
  }
```

`textPipeDump` is scalding `MultipleTextLine` field object

```
case class MultipleTextLineFiles(p : String*) extends FixedPathSource(p:_*) with TextLineScheme
```

I have a case class to split and grab the fields that I want from that text line and thats the object `ss`

Here is my stack trace:

```
Exception in thread "IPC Client (47) connection to /127.0.0.1:55977 from job_201306241658_232590" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
    at org.apache.hadoop.io.IOUtils.closeStream(IOUtils.java:226)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client$Connection.close(Client.java:903)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client$Connection.run(Client.java:800)
28079664 [main] ERROR cascading.flow.stream.TrapHandler - caught Throwable, no trap available, rethrowing
cascading.pipe.OperatorException: [WritableSequenceFile(h...][com.twitter.scalding.GroupBuilder$$anonfun$1.apply(GroupBuilder.scala:189)] operator Every failed executing operation: MRMAggregator[decl:'value']
    at cascading.flow.stream.AggregatorEveryStage.receive(AggregatorEveryStage.java:136)
    at cascading.flow.stream.AggregatorEveryStage.receive(AggregatorEveryStage.java:39)
    at cascading.flow.stream.OpenReducingDuct.receive(OpenReducingDuct.java:49)
    at cascading.flow.stream.OpenReducingDuct.receive(OpenReducingDuct.java:28)
    at cascading.flow.hadoop.stream.HadoopGroupGate.run(HadoopGroupGate.java:90)
    at cascading.flow.hadoop.FlowReducer.reduce(FlowReducer.java:133)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.ReduceTask.runOldReducer(ReduceTask.java:520)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.ReduceTask.run(ReduceTask.java:421)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Child$4.run(Child.java:255)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:396)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1178)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Child.main(Child.java:249)
Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
    at scala.collection.mutable.ListBuffer.$plus$eq(ListBuffer.scala:168)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ListBuffer.$plus$eq(ListBuffer.scala:45)
    at scala.collection.generic.Growable$$anonfun$$plus$plus$eq$1.apply(Growable.scala:48)
    at scala.collection.generic.Growable$$anonfun$$plus$plus$eq$1.apply(Growable.scala:48)
    at scala.collection.immutable.List.foreach(List.scala:318)
    at scala.collection.generic.Growable$class.$plus$plus$eq(Growable.scala:48)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ListBuffer.$plus$plus$eq(ListBuffer.scala:176)
    at scala.collection.immutable.List.$colon$colon$colon(List.scala:127)
    at scala.collection.immutable.List.$plus$plus(List.scala:193)
    at com.twitter.algebird.ListMonoid.plus(Monoid.scala:86)
    at com.twitter.algebird.ListMonoid.plus(Monoid.scala:84)
    at com.twitter.scalding.KeyedList$$anonfun$sum$1.apply(TypedPipe.scala:264)
    at com.twitter.scalding.MRMAggregator.aggregate(Operations.scala:279)
    at cascading.flow.stream.AggregatorEveryStage.receive(AggregatorEveryStage.java:128)
    ... 12 more
```

When I execute the map reduce job for small data set I don't get the error. Which means that as the data increase number of items/product_ids that I index for words like New or old etc get bigger which cause the Heap Size to overflow.

So, the question is how can avoid java heap size overflow and accomplish this task.

Comment: Just how many product IDs are there per key?

Comment: I don't have a exact number it varies because some key words only return 1 or 2 items but some may return 100000

Comment: Well, if you can make it lazy, that should do it.  Otherwise, you might have to do the operation in several passes so you don't accumulate too much data in memory (it looks to me like you have all product IDs for all keys in memory at the same time).  Can't help with the details, though--just the strategy.